# C - Print a char returned by a function

Tags: c

UPDATE:
The final if statement `if(lettergrade <= 'A' && lettergrade >= 'F')` was incorrect as the ascii value for F (70) is greater than A (65).

I'm trying to print a character returned by a function in C.

My function, assignletter, is given a float, and returns a character.

When I run the program as is:

```
skirchbaum:~/workspace/HMWK/HMWK4 $ ./assignletter 
Enter pointsgrade
100
Pointsgrade: 100.00 Lettergrade:
```

Nothing gets printed for lettergrade (I have tried multiple cases - 100.1, 1, etc)

What am I doing wrong?

CODE:

```
/* Input: a grade as points
   Functionality: converts point grade into letter grade
   Output: a char representing the letter grade, or -1 if error

   LETTER GRADE BREAKDOWN:
   A = 100 - 91
   B = 90 - 81
   C = 80 - 71
   D = 70 - 61
   F = 60 and below
*/


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DEBUG 1

char assignletter(float pointsgrade);

char lettergrade;
float pointsgrade;

int main(){
    //Input a pointsgrade for debugging
    #ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Enter pointsgrade\n");
    scanf("%f", &pointsgrade);
    lettergrade = assignletter(pointsgrade);
    printf("Pointsgrade: %.2f Lettergrade: %c\n", pointsgrade, lettergrade);
    #endif
}

char assignletter(float pointsgrade){

    char lettergrade;

    //Grade A
    if(pointsgrade <= 100 && pointsgrade >= 91){
        lettergrade = 'A';
    }

    //Grade B
    if(pointsgrade <= 90 && pointsgrade >= 81){
        lettergrade = 'B';
    }

    //Grade C
    if(pointsgrade <= 80 && pointsgrade >= 71){
        lettergrade = 'C';
    }

    //Grade D
    if(pointsgrade <= 70 && pointsgrade >= 61){
        lettergrade = 'D';
    }

    //Grade F
    if(pointsgrade <= 60){
        lettergrade = 'F';
    }

    //Return letter grade or -1 if error
    if(lettergrade <= 'A' && lettergrade >= 'F'){
        return lettergrade;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `lettegrade` cannot be less than/equal to `'A'` and greater than/equal to `'F'`. Switch the operators

Comment: But doesn't A have a higher value than F? @EliSadoff

Comment: No. `'A'` is `65` and `'F'` is `70`.

Comment: Oh I see now, thank you.@EliSadoff

Comment: What happens if pointsgrade is e.g. 90.1?

Comment: @BjornA. didn't catch that. Updated to reflect those cases (decimals inbetween grades)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the condition is not well formed, the 'F' is 70 in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) and the 'A' is 65 so

```
if (lettergrade <= 'A' && lettergrade >= 'F') {
    return lettergrade;
}
```

won't evaluate to true as lettergrade ('A') is less than 70 ('F') and not bigger than it

you'd rather do it this way

```
if (lettergrade >= 'A' && lettergrade <= 'F') {
    return lettergrade;
}
```

by flipping the bigger than and less than signs

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `lettergrade` to an ASCII value between A(65) and F(70).

But, in the condition, you are checking if value is less than A(65) and more than F(70).

Naturally, if `lettergrade` falls between A(65) and B(70) (which it will), the `return` statement won't be evaluated.

Replace

```
    if(lettergrade <= 'A' && lettergrade >= 'F'){
        return lettergrade;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
```

With

```
    if(lettergrade >= 'A' && lettergrade <= 'F'){
        return lettergrade;
    }
    return -1;
```

As an extra tip,i would advise you to do away with the `else` statement as well. The reason being that the control will reach `return -1` only when the other `return` statement has not been executed.

Comment: it doesn't make any difference, did you try it? you might want to remove your answer to avoid anyone down voting it

Comment: i just improvised one step further and removed the useless else statement.

Comment: omg!, you're right ,my bad I'm sorry for that, it's really not obvious at the first glance, it might be better if you provided some explanation